# How do I run a user defined function in a scrapy spider?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

Since we run scrapy spiders with its own terminal commands, how can I run my own defined functions?

Example below:

```
import scrapy


class Fcc(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "fcc"
    start_urls = ["http://freecodecamp.org/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.css("a::attr(href)").getall():
            yield {
            "url": link,
            }

    def add(self):
        with open("links.txt", "a") as f:
            f.write(next(self.parse()))
```

So now if I run the spider from terminal by passing the below command, It will only execute the **parse** function. So how can I run the **add** function when I want to?

> scrapy runspider fcc_spider.py

Because this will help me working with data I crawl from any website.

Ps. This is just an example, please don't give specific solutions for only this code, give solutions that can be used in any situation.

Comment: In a normal Python program, you'd pass command-line arguments and use `sys.argv` to read them.  I don't know if `scrapy` passes the command-line through to the script, but it's worth checking.

Answer (score 0):

By default Scrapy execute `start_requests` or `parse` methods. You can use `def __init__` to check for command line params and run your target function.

Comment: Can you elaborate or share a good scrapy tutorial as I don't know much about scrapy?

Comment: @RohanLalwani What about Scrapy Documentation: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

You can run your user defined functions by calling them in one of your Scrapy callbacks.

You could call it before or after the `for` loop inside the `parse` method (remember of the asynchronous nature of Scrapy).

You could also define a constructor for your Spider and pass the contents of the links.txt file to it.

Here is an example from the Scrapy documentation: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#spider-arguments

Comment: I know nothing about asynchronous programming and scrapy's environment, Do you think that I should learn asynchronous programming before proceeding ahead with my scrapy project? and if you have a good tutorial that can teach me about scrapy and how it works, it would be very appreciated. Because scrapy documentation is hard to understand for me.

Comment: @RohanLalwani I believe that you do not need to learn asynchronous programming before starting using Scrapy, you can learn from Scrapy, it could be a good experience.
Check the Scrapy [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/), with time you get familiarized with it, and with the Scrapy [data flow](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html#data-flow).

Answer (score 0):

In Python, it's possible to create **Inner Functions** (function in function).

A function defined inside another function is known as an inner function or a nested function. In Python, this kind of function can access names in the enclosing function. Here’s an example of how to create an inner function in Python:

```
def outer_func():
     def inner_func():
         print("Hello, World!")
     inner_func()

outer_func()
```

Output:

```
Hello, World!
```

In this code, you define inner_func() inside outer_func() to print the Hello, World! message to the screen. To do that, you call inner_func() on the last line of outer_func(). This is the quickest way to write an inner function in Python. However, inner functions provide a lot of interesting possibilities beyond what you see in this example.

*Read more [here](https://realpython.com/inner-functions-what-are-they-good-for/)*

**IMPLEMENTATION Example**

Based on that you can create a function in one of the Scrapy functions, and call it within that function.

```
def parse(self, response):
    def function_name(name):
        to_return = "hello {}".format(name)
        return to_return

    #Some code here...

    pharam = function_name(name)
```